# ASP.NET MVC3, How to set global variable which can be used in Controller and Model too?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

All my controller has this code on the top of class.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
//
// GET: /Reports/

string userName;
string uid;
string accountType;
int companyCode;

protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);

    string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
    HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[cookieName];


    if (authCookie != null)
    {
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    string userData = authTicket.UserData;

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var userInfo = serializer.Deserialize<MemberModel>(userData);

    userName = userInfo.firstName + " " + userInfo.lastName;
    uid = userInfo.uid;
    accountType = userInfo.accountType;
    companyCode = userInfo.companyCode;
    }
}
```

Because, every controller need to have user information that's in cookie.

I think this is not right way writing that code in every controller.

Also, Even I can not use that method in my MODEL.

```
base.Initialize(requestContext); <= 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Initialize'
```

So, I'd like to know how to set that method as GLOBAL variable to use in any controller and model.

Anybody knows, please advice me~

[EDIT]

[image]

Thank you!

[EDIT]

I define as above code in HomeController and try to call the userName in testController.
but it is empty. (Error is gone now)

In TestController,

```
[HttpGet]
public void test()
{
    Response.Write(MemberModelProvider.UserName);
    Response.Write(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["UserName"]);
}
```

**it print nothing...**

What am I doing wrong?

I very appreciate for your help!

Comment: Why don't you write a class that handles this?

Comment: yeah, that's good way too. but the class can not be located in Model, because it makes an error. then where that class should be located, and how can I fix that method to make model can use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put that information to live in the HttpContext.Items. This collection lives while the request, so you won't have any troubles with different requests accessing the same code:

```
public abstract class AuthenticatedController : Controller
{

  protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
  {
    base.Initialize(requestContext);

    string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
    HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[cookieName];


    if (authCookie != null)
    {
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    string userData = authTicket.UserData;

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var userInfo = serializer.Deserialize<MemberModel>(userData);
    MemberModelProvider.Current = userInfo;
    }
  }
}

public class HomeController :  AuthenticatedController {

    //Your actions here...
}

public class TestController :  AuthenticatedController {

    //Your actions here...
}

public class MemberModelProvider {
    public static MemberModel Current {
        get { return (MemberModel)HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentMemberModel"];}
        set { HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentMemberModel"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Then, anytime you need to use it, you just call `MemberModelProvider.Current`.

Comment: there is an error on HttpContext, error message say 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HttpContext.get'. Do you know how I can solve it? Thank you!
'

Comment: I've updated the answer because of an error. Maybe it is the problem.

Comment: I updated my question, could you take look plz? and is it possible use that in Model file? (Not Controller) Or do I have to pass as parameter?

Comment: you have to put the MemberModelProvider outside your controller class :)

Comment: aha! thank you! Now the error is gone. and I call MemberModelProvider.Current from the other controller file. but MemberModelProvider.Current is empty. I expected if I define the MemberModelProvider in Home Controller then I could use the MemberModelProvider in any file(Controllers and Models). Did I something wrong?

Comment: You will need to put that code in an ActionFilter, so that code is executed for each controller: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: Another option is to create a `BaseController` with the common code. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer again, I can not decide which I need to use. which is better way? which one you recommend?

Comment: The easiest will be the base controller.

Answer (score 4):

Create a common base class for controllers and make all actual controllers inherit that

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected readonly MemberModel Member;

    protected BaseController()
    {
        Member = getUserInfoFromCookie();
    }
}
public class TestController : BaseController
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can execute that piece of code every time each action is executed using an Action Filter. You can find mor info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609.aspx)